# htaccess - mod rewrite - rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to ask for help with the following:
I have for example this rule mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^adverts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adverts.php?kat=$1&podkat=$2 [L]
```

I want to rewrite the URL www.x.cz/adverts/category/subcategory to www.x.cz/adverts.php?cat=category&subcat=subcategory.

**This works,** but problem arise in that case, if the URL is for example www.x.cz/adverts/category/subcategory/xxx (shortly after another slash is some other text string). Then there is error 500. How could i solve this problem? (I would like the server to return 404 or do the same as referring to the URL www.x.cz/adverts.php?kat=category&podkat=subcategory - as if there was not the another string).

Thank you all for your willingness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick for making it match even if it has additional parts to the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^adverts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/(.*))?$ adverts.php?kat=$1&podkat=$2 [L]
```